# Reading content from a pdf based on some key

Tags: java, pdf

I have several pdfs with some codes scatterred across (no fixed position) as below:

```
oneCode=abcd
twoCode=4566
```

I want to parse every pdf to find keys "oneCode" or "twoCode" and get the corresponding values from inside my java program.

Is such a functionality available in any open source pdf parsers like PDFBox, etc. ?

Can any one please point to a example ?

Additionally, my pdf's could be of varying size from huge to very small and at a time I might need to parse thousands of PDFs from my program. So parsing complete pdf and then searching for the key from the parsed text might become very very slow.

So is there any existing functionality which could help in my scenario ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Well, you obviously will have to parse the complete pdfs (usually in a page by page manner), but while doing so you can search that content for key-value pairs and later on work with the collection of those pairs instead of the whole content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do faster than a linear search. Just the action of sorting or indexing will take at least order O(n), so even if there are readers with fast indexed search, they require some lead preprocessing time.

You need to find a reader that can transfer the data into memory quickly, so that you can read the data quickly.